# Magento 2: currency drop down is not showing?

Tags: magento2.2.3

I have set up the currency according to store view but when I see the frontend, it's not displaying.

I have done all the things. Moved the currency using the default.xml file.

```
<move element="currency" destination="header.sections"/>
```

Call this from my custom phtml file.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency') ?>
```

when I open the template hints, the currency file is calling from the vendor module but not displaying in frontend.

See the below image.

[image]

Is there anything which I had missed out.

Comment: Have you set the currency rates?

Comment: yes, I have set current rates.

Comment: Before the code you have used to move the currency, does currency switcher displayed?

Comment: wait, I will check in the RWD theme.

Comment: no only language switcher is showing in RWD & my custom theme.

Comment: So language switcher showing only in RWD and not in your custom theme?

Comment: language switcher is showing in my theme as well. All the links/dropdown are showing which I override/moved (wishlist, language switcher, mini cart, my account) except currency switcher.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104684/discussion-between-aravind-and-pankaj).